# Problems with CoreDataBooks Example from Apple

Tags: iphone, datamodel, core-data

I am currently playing with CoreData and have a problem with the CoreDataBooks Example from Apple.

Basically I just wanted to extend the data model. I updated the model class aswell and no compiler error, butr a crash when I want to start the example.

Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 UserInfo=0x1316ce0 "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)", {
    URL = file://localhost/.../CoreDataBooks.sqlite;
...some nonsense info ...
  reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}

Do I need to updat the sqlite database ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I needed to version the datamodel before changing anything that would ensure that the model does migrate automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you modify or update the data model, make sure you:

1. Add `NSManagedObject` class header and implementations for any new or modified entities (select the entity in the data modeler and use `New File... > NSManagedObject` to create new class files).
2. Delete your app from the iPhone simulator or device, before rebuilding and reinstalling. You can worry about migration issues later.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the NSManagedObject. I created a "Managed Object Class" form the Entity I changed, so nothing should break there, 

I also delete the app from the device, but that can not really be the solution when I want to update my app in the future.

Comment: Until you write migration routines, the schema of your device/Simulator database will be different from the schema of your modified data model. If you try to run your application with the old database and the new data model, you will get an exception due to the inconsistency between the two. Deleting the application from the device/Simulator is probably the easiest way to manage testing between data model updates, until you're ready to write migration routines.